# What does this sort of notation mean?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, notation

I'm revising for my exams at the moment and am seeing this notation everywhere

[image]

Can anyone tell me what these mean?

Comment: Related post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98155/

Comment: that post doesn't answer my question though unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions on either side of the equals sign are called [term symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_symbol#Symbol). They specify the state of a system of electrons and they have the form $^{2S+1}L_J$. So for example $^{2}D_{5/2}$ corresponds to a system of electrons with $2S+1=2$, or in other words $S=1/2$; $L=2$; and $J=5/2$. They way I got $L=2$ was to use the correspondence $S \leftrightarrow 0,P \leftrightarrow 1,D \leftrightarrow 2,F \leftrightarrow 3,G \leftrightarrow 4, \cdots$

I believe that the arrows indicate that there has been a transition between two states.